# MySql Insert into spefic row where username = something

Tags: mysql

I have a table called "Users" and on that table I have a user called "user1" and that same row also have a column called "Hwid" WHat would the command look like if i want to only insert a value to that user?

This is what I've tried so far `INSERT INTO users WHERE username = user1 (hwid) VALUE 12`

Comment: `UPDATE` is your friend.

Comment: @raina77ow I'll look into that.

Comment: what do you mean `INSERT` + `WHERE` ??? when you insert, you just add one new record. You can do any condition **before** you insert, but not during :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use UPDATE if you want to change any value to that row

```
UPDATE Users SET Hwid='12' WHERE username = 'user1';
```